# While loop modify global variable

Tags: python, variables, gspread

I thought loops in python do not change our global variables; however, the code below gives 10 as a result. Can someone explain what is happening here?

```
source_col_numbers = 9
i = 1
columns = {}

while i <= source_col_numbers:
    columns[i] = list(filter(None , source.sheet1.col_values(i)))
    i += 1

print(i)
```

Comment: "I thought loops in python do not change our global variables" that is not correct.

Comment: you are starting from value 1 and entrying loop 9 times, thats why you are getting i = 10

Comment: What made you think this in the first place? As juanpa says, it's not at all true.

Comment: Even loop variables are accessible after the loop ;)

Comment: Perhaps you were expecting block scope? Python does not have block scope

Comment: thank you guys, is there any way in python to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `i` as a global variable and then you are using it in the loop.
So, whatever changes you make to `i` in your program will be applied on that `i` since it's a global variable.

Global variable means `i` has a global scope. If you had created `i` inside a function, it would have a local scope and could not be accessed outside of the function.

So in your case, changes will be made and output will be `10`.

Comment: Oh dear, that is not what a global variable means at all. It simply states that the variable exists in the "global" scope, you can think of that as the top level of the module. However, global variables can be freely accessed, created and deleted, and do not have to survive as long as the program lives.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh yeah yeah, my bad. I wanted to mean something but it came out in a different way. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, appreciate the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Loops do change global variables, so for each iteration of the loop, `i` will be incremented by 1.